# What structure should a TestClass have in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a class responsible for a plot generation:

```
class PlotX:

  def one(param1)

  def two(param1)

  ...
```

and I want to test it. I group all test methods inside a TestPlotX class:

```
class TestPlotX:

  data_for_test_one = (
   (
     # Input
     # Test that method one does ...
     pd.DataFrame()

     # Expected
     pd.DataFrame()
   ),
   (.. more test data ..)
  )

  @pytest.mark.parametrize('test_input, expected', data_for_test_one)
  def test_one(self, test_input, expected):
       plot = PlotX()
       actual = plot.one(test_input)

       assert_frame_equal(actual, expected)

  data_for_test_two = (
   (
     # Input
     # Test that method two does ...
     pd.DataFrame()

     # Expected
     pd.DataFrame()
   ),
   (.. more test data ..)
  )

  @pytest.mark.parametrize('test_input, expected', data_for_test_two)
  def test_two(self, test_input, expected):
       plot = PlotX()
       actual = plot.two(test_input)

       assert_frame_equal(actual, expected)
```

I have two main issues with my current setup:

1) I feel like the test data (data_for_test_one) doesn't really belong there. Is there a better place for it?

2) I'm instantiating the class with every test method, which I need so that I have a new object, but doesn't pytest have a better way of doing that?

**Edit:**

I see I can use something like this:

```
class TestPlotX:
  def setup(self):
    self.plot = PlotX()
```

but I don't know if there will be a new plot instance for every test method.